# If $\bar M A M^T=MAM^\dagger$ for all real $A$, must $M$ be real?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Suppose M is an $n \times n$ complex matrix, if $$\bar M A M^T=MAM^\dagger$$ for all real $n \times n$ matrices $A$ does this imply that $M$ must also be real? Here $\bar M$ denotes the element-wise complex conjugate of $M$, $M^T$ denotes the transpose and $M^\dagger$ denotes the conjugate-transpose. I think that this is true and am unable to find a counter-example.

Answer (score 1):

No. First, notice that your condition is equivalent to saying that 
$M A M^\dagger$ is real for all real $A.$ Second, suppose that $M$ is diagonal with diagonal elements $m_1, \dotsc, m_n.$ Your condition is then equivalent to saying that $m_i \overline{m_j}$ is real for every $i, j.$ But that is true if $m_i = c_i m_1, $ for some real $c_2, \dotsc, c_n,$ and $m_1$ *arbitrary complex*.

Comment: To get the product $m_i \overline{m_j}$, you're suggesting that we take $A_{i,j} = 1$ and all other entries zero, correct?

Comment: @Chris if you like, but the point is that the $ij$-th entry of the matrix is $m_i \overline{m_j} a_{ij},$ for an arbitrary $A.$ In particular, if all entries of $A$ are real and non-zero, all the products whereof I speak are real (and this is necessary and sufficient).

Comment: Right, I wanted to be explicit (partly so OP would see it if he were confused).

Comment: @IgorRivin What about when $M$ is not diagonalizable? For example $M = \begin{pmatrix}
i & 1 \\
0 & i
\end{pmatrix}$, the diagonal elements are real multiples of one another but taking $A=I$ to be the identity we get $MAM^\dagger= \begin{pmatrix}
2 & -i \\
i & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ which is not real.

Comment: @Alex I was not diagonalizing anything, I just gave a counterexample.

Comment: @IgorRivin My mistake, I thought you were stating the conditions in which OP's equation is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

The condition means that $MAM^\dagger$ is a real matrix. If you write $M=X+iY$ where $X,Y$ are real, your condition amounts to $XAY^T=YAX^T$ for every real $A$, i.e. $Y\otimes X=X\otimes Y$. Thus $X,Y$ are linearly dependent, meaning that $M$ must be a complex multiple of a real matrix.

Comment: Do you have a proof or a reference?

Comment: @gene What do you mean? Just set $M$ to any complex multiple of a real matrix and you'll see the equality holds.

Comment: @user1511 Yes I understand that this will work but are there any other matrices $M$ that will work? Does $\bar M A M^T=MAM^\dagger$ imply necessarily that $M=re^{i \theta} B$ for some real matrix $B$? I'm trying to understand the conditions required of $M$ for a factorisation algorithm that I'm programming.